# variable declared in knockout JS is not available in html

Tags: html, knockout.js

we have a dialog which is rendered in browser. Browser runs the knockout JS. We are passing the view model from java to the JS. then using that view model in html to create elements in the dialog.

The view model is a map of string and object. Existing code works correctly.

Now I add a new variable in view model and pass it to the JS, then that variable should be available in HTML.

BUT any new variable added in not available in HTML.

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure on exactly what you're doing when you say "I add a new variable in view model and pass it to the JS". Surely the view-model _is_ JS? Can you add some JavaScript to your post showing how you're adding this new variable and exactly what "pass it to the JS" entails?

Answer (score 0):

Knockout wasn't really designed with adding variables midstream in mind. The proper way to use Knockout is to pre-define your view model with all possible variables included. Any variables whose values are not yet known should be assigned a default value of null or blank. Then, later on, when your variable values show up, you simply update the observables that are already part of the view model.